# Select range of variables with PROC SQL in SAS

Tags: sql, sas, proc

I want to select rows based on a range of similar variables meet certain conditions:

```
proc sql;
  create table2 as
  select * from table1 
  where proc1 in ('111', '222', '333') or
        proc2 in ('111', '222', '333') or
        proc3 in ('111', '222', '333');
quit;
```

Is there a way I can select the variables more efficiently? In SAS' `data step`, I can use `proc1-proc3`, but this can't be done in `proc SQL`.

Comment: Probably you need to look to Dynamic Query. Where using the parameter you build the `WHERE` condition. Otherwise you cant select what field would be check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to do exactly that, but there are some options that will probably suite you.

First write a sql statement that writes these conditions to a macro variable `proc_conditions`

```
proc sql;
  select compbl(name ||' in ('111', '222', '333')')
  into : proc_conditions separated by ' or '
  from sasHelp.vcolumn
  where libName = 'WORK'
    and memName = 'TABLE2'
    and upcase(Name) like 'PROC%'
  ;
```

Note that libName's and memName's are always uppercase in the meta data, while field Name's or mixed case (but case insensitive). I added `Compbl` to reduce multiple blanks to singles, but that is not required.

You might check the result is `proc1 in ('111', '222', '333') or proc2 in ('111', '222', '333') or proc3 in ('111', '222', '333')` by writing it to the log.

```
  %put &proc_conditions;
```

Then just use it

```
  create table2 as
  select * from table1 
  where &proc_conditions;
quit;
```